# Julia's equivalent of MATLAB's inpolygon()

Tags: julia, julia-jump

Is there such function in Julia?

Desperately trying to migrate to Julia from MATLAB, but still finding myself dependent on it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GeometricalPredicates package has `inpolygon`: https://github.com/JuliaGeometry/GeometricalPredicates.jl

Answer (score 3):

You could also investigate [Luxor.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Luxor.jl/blob/master/src/polygons.jl#L186-L229):

```
using Luxor

p1 = Point(0,   0)
p2 = Point(10,  0) 
p3 = Point(10, 10) 
p4 = Point(0,  10) 

isinside(Point(5, 5), [p1, p2, p3, p4]) # true

isinside(Point(15, 5), [p1, p2, p3, p4]) # false
```

But make sure to check for vertex and edge exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

The [`PolygonOps`](https://github.com/JuliaGeometry/PolygonOps.jl) package does point-in-polygon testing too.

It's more user-friendly, but possibly slower, than `GeometricalPredicates`.

(Hat tip: [Julia forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/inpolygon-usage/39226/4).)